# Error importing SSIS package to MSDB in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I am getting this error when i try to import a package to the MSDB in SSMS, i guess it got something to do with roles? But where do i change this?

[image]

Comment: The user you are using does not have `EXECUTE` permission to `MSDB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to add yourself to one of the SSIS fixed roles (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141053(v=sql.105).aspx)